# How to pull user info from twitter api

Tags: asp.net, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

I trying to implement login using twitter in my asp.net application. I am following this article to do this functionality:

[Login with twitter using Oauth](http://www.dotnetbull.com/2013/05/login-with-twitter-using-oauth.html)

It give me only screen name and user id. i want to get more info like username, location and email(if possible). Can anyone tell me how to get these info.

Answer (score 1):

The field *screen_name* is Twitter's user id. You cannot get the email. You can get the location of the user in a String field called *location* in the same object, *user*.

You can find the full description of the object user in this [link](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/users).

As a side note, you can get the location as geo. coordinates in every tweet. It is the field *coordinates* in the object *tweet*. But in my experience it is hardly ever informed.

As for the code for the actual access, looking at the link you provide in your question, you could build up a method like the one I've tried to write below. Sorry I cannot test it (actually I don't know much of .NET), but I hope it won't get you long to get it from this point. This would be calling [GET users show](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/users/show) and the implementation would be similar to this:

```
public static HttpWebRequest getUserData(string oauth_consumer_key, string oauth_consumer_secret, string oauth_access_token, string oauth_token_secret, string user_screen_name)
    {
        string updateStatusURL = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?screen_name=" + user_screen_name;

        string outUrl;
        string OAuthHeaderPOST = OAuthUtility.GetAuthorizationHeaderForPost_OR_QueryParameterForGET(new Uri(updateStatusURL), callbackUrl, httpMethod.POST.ToString(), oauth_consumer_key, oauth_consumer_secret, oauth_access_token, oauth_token_secret, out outUrl);

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(outUrl);
        request.Method = httpMethod.GET.ToString();
        request.Headers["Authorization"] = OAuthHeaderPOST;

        return request;

    }

}
```

And afterwards you will have to read the results of the `request`.
Hope it helps!

Comment: i have made some fixes now it say 401 unauthorize :(

Comment: Sorry! I'm completely blind of course... What do you see as `request.Headers`? It should include something like: `Authorization: 
        OAuth oauth_consumer_key="...", 
              oauth_nonce="...", 
              oauth_signature="...", 
              oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", 
              oauth_timestamp="...", 
              oauth_token="...", 
              oauth_version="1.0"`. More info [here](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/authorizing-requests)

Comment: yes it is exactlly like this.. when i request "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json" this url it works fine

Comment: Well. I doesnt make sense to me... If *account/verify_credentials* works, then *users/show* should work as well. Running out of ideas, honestly. Maybe you could try the *signature generator* below in [this link](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/users/show) -you need to log in to twitter 1st in your browser, and it provides you a `curl` command you can try. Anyhow, it should work just the same as *verify_credentials*, I guess it won't give you additional info....